# Fourier sine series limiting behavior

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

By the Weierstrass M-test, there is uniform convergence on $[0,\pi]$ for

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}$$

Exchanging limit and sum we have $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$.

(1) Is it true that on $(0,\pi]$

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$$

and $\lim_{x \to 0+} f'(x) = \infty?$

(2) What is

$$\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2x} = ?$$

I see that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty $$

but switching limit and sum may not be permitted here.

My concern is sometimes in general we can have $f'(0)$ exist but have $f'(x)$ not continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: you mean $f'(0)$ instead of $f'(x)$, right?

Comment: I do believe you meant to say:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$
Unless you meant to say
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x$$
^ Both of these are correct, but what you have is not.

Comment: Sorry I botched this up.  I have edited to state the questions more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Since, $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(nx)$ is bounded on any compact subset of $(0,\pi)$, then [Dirichlet's Test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence#Theorem) for uniform convergence guarantees that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ uniformly converges for $x$ on any compact subset of $(0,\pi)$.

Therefore, we assert that for $x\in (0,\pi)$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}\tag 1$$

Note that the right-hand side of $(1)$ fails to exist at $x=0$.

Inasmuch as it represents the function $-\log\left(2\sin(x/2)\right)$ for $x\in(0,\pi)$, then the limit as $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}=\infty$.  And we are done!

Comment: Thanks.  This helps with the first question (edited to make clear).

Comment: I do see $\lim \sum \frac{\cos nx}{n} = \infty$.  I don't see the answer to the second question yet. Functions like $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ have defined derivatives at $0$ but $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}=-\log\left(2\sin(x/2)\right)$ for $x\in(0,\pi)$.  What is the limit of this as $x\to 0^+$?

Comment: So to complete argument we can use the mean value theorem and say $\frac{f(x) -f(0)}{x} = f'(c)$. From your closed form we see $\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0+}f'(c) = \infty$ since $c$ is between $0$ and $x$.  Nice that there is a closed form in this case.  Of course the other answer takes a more general approach.

Comment: @sas Using available information is actually a good thing here.  You posed a specific problem and this os a specific answer.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

We can also attack this thing directly. Sketch: Note that there exists $c>0$ such that $\sin x \ge cx$ for $x\in [0,1].$ Let $x=1/N$ where $N\in \mathbb N$ is large.  Then

$$\tag 1\frac{f(1/N)}{1/N} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} N\frac{\sin (n/N)}{n^2} + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} N\frac{\sin (n/N)}{n^2}.$$

The first sum on the right is at least $c \sum_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{1}{n}.$ The second sum on the right, in absolute value, is no more than $N\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^2},$ which is no more than $N\int_N^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^2}\, dx = N\dfrac{1}{N}= 1.$ Thus $(1)$ is at least $c\ln N - 1 \to \infty.$

Comment: Well done as usual.  And nicely "sketched."  (+1)

Comment: @MarkViola  Thanks, and +1 for your solution above.

Comment: That is a good general approach without knowing the closed form of the derivative series. Thanks.